# How to detect when a running script is modified and reload?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an AutoHotkey file running on a Google Drive folder on a remote machine and i'm trying to make it reload itself whenever it detect it got modified.

Is there a method to subscribe to file changes without having to use loops?

Answer (score 0):

You need a timer to detect when the running script gets modified:

```
#Persistent

SetTimer Reload_this_Script, 500

            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

Reload_this_Script:
FileGetTime, FileMTime, %A_ScriptFullPath%, M ;  Retrieves the modification time and stores it in FileMTime.
If ((A_Now - FileMTime) < 1)
    Reload
return
```